# How to insert POINT from two values

Tags: sql

Say I have a table SpatialItem that wants a position as POINT, how do I insert the values from latitude and longitude?

```
CREATE TABLE SpatialItem (
  itemId      INTEGER NOT NULL,
  position    POINT
) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

It should be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO SpatialItem
(itemId position=POINT(Latitude, Longtitude))
SELECT ItemID Latitude Longtitude
FROM Item;
```

Comment: See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-spatial-data.html (sorry, on a phone). Also, MyISAM has a lot of drawbacks.

Comment: You might want to ask at gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Schwern I'm using MySQL5.5 where MyISAM is the only one supports spatial index. I checked the doc, just don't know how to use "set" in INSERT SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert with select works by the select mapping the columns directly onto the fields to be inserted. The fields coming out of the select have to line up with the ones insert expects.

That means it's the select that has to translate the latitude and longitude into a point.

```
INSERT INTO SpatialItem
(itemId, position)
SELECT ItemID, POINT(Latitude, Longtitude)
FROM Item
```